# In Espresso, how can I perform an action on all matching views without triggering an AmbiguousViewMatcherException?

Tags: android, android-espresso, android-testing, hamcrest

I'm using Espresso to run automated UI tests on an Android app. I want to perform an action on *all* views that match specified conditions. Espresso does use an `allOf()` method to find all views that a matcher matches. However, commands such as `onView(withText("some text")).perform(click())` would throw an `AmbiguousViewMatcherException` if there is more than one match.

I do have a method for getting the nth matching view when there are multiple matches.

```
    private static Matcher<View> getElementFromMatchAtPosition(final Matcher<View> matcher, final int position) {
        return new BaseMatcher<View>() {
            int counter = 0;

            @Override
            public boolean matches(final Object item) {
                if (matcher.matches(item)) {
                    if(counter == position) {
                        counter++;
                        return true;
                    }
                    counter++;
                }
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void describeTo(final Description description) {
                description.appendText("Element at hierarchy position " + position);
            }
        };
    }
```

Sure, I could use this method to loop through every view. But is there a more elegant solution?

And what if I don't know how many matching views there are?

Comment: How have you been using `allOf()`?

Comment: I just realized I made a mistake. It turns out `allOf()` means all matchers, not all views matching a specific matcher. D'oh!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you may have been using `allOf()` incorrectly.

As you noted in your comment, `allOf()` should be used with matchers. You can then pick all the unique aspects of the view you want to select, comma separated.

Here's an example:

`onView(allOf(isDescendantOfA(withId(R.id.input)), withText("jeff@bob.com"))).check(matches(isDisplayed()));`